# Table alignments. How to make a \hline in the middle of a table

Tags: tables, hline

I was wondering how to create these tables in LaTeX. How to have the ***title*** adjusted to the left of the table. And how to color a `\hline` and how to put it in the middle of a table. It almost seems like a table in a table

[image]

Comment: The answer to "How to put it in the middle" is easy: `\cline` instead of `\hline`.

Comment: Please extend your question with an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. IFrom showed image can be conculeded that simpe `cline` will not give what you expected. It may be `cmidrule(l){3-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}` defined in the `\booktabs` package (for the second table) what you afer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
text & \multicolumn{4}{c}{text}\\
\arrayrulecolor{blue}\cmidrule{2-5}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay.. How do I skip text in a single cell? The [table]{xcolor} clashes with another package I use to be able to skip in a cell.  For example from the picture **Since\\May 31, 1994**

Comment: What do you mean with "skip text"? Does it refer to manual linebreaks inside of a table cell? If so, how do you currently achieve them? Also, which package clash are you referring to? A complete minimal working example would be really helpful. Could you edit your question to provide such a MWE?

Comment: ```\usepackage{tabularray} %to skip lines in a table need  tabularray.sty
        \begin{tblr}{l r r r}
&{ \textbf{Float Adj Mkt \\
Cap\\
(USD Billions)}}
&
{\textbf{Index\\Wt. (\%)}}
& \textbf{Sector} \\
\hline 
MICROCHIP TECHNOLOGY & 39.13  &  1.19  & Info Tech \\
\end{tblr}```

Comment: Your original question starts with "I was wondering how to create these tables [...]", so I was under the impression you wanted to recreate the exact same tables shown in the screenshot. The code you posted in your comment, however results in a table that is quite different, not only regarding the contents, but also regarding the number of columns, alignment and the missing shared column headers and other elements. Please clarify what exactly you would like to achieve.

Comment: Also, you can achieve manual linebreaks in table cells also without the use of `tabularray`. Are you more interested on an approach using a regular `tabular` (probably in combination with some other packages, such as `xcolor` for colored lines, `booktabs` for horizontal lines with improved spacing, `siunitx` for improved alignment of numners and `makecell` for column headers with manual linebreaks) or are you more interested in a `tabularray`-based solution?

Comment: I would rather not use ``tabulararray`` the reason I liked it (I found it yesterday) was it was simple inside the document ``{text \\ text}`` but what I don't like about it is it is very cumbersome  outside. Now I really don't like it because it clashes with the solution you gave me.

Comment: For manual linebreaks inside of cells of a regular `tabular`, take a look at the `makecell` package and its `\thead` and `\makecell` commands. What about [my other comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599801/table-alignments-how-to-make-a-hline-in-the-middle-of-a-table/599810?noredirect=1#comment1504941_599810)?